# What does "List * list" do in Learn C the Hard Way Ex32

Tags: c, list

In lcthw ex32, functions are definde as:

```
List *List_create();
void List_destroy(List * list);
void List_clear(List * list);
void List_clear_destroy(List * list);
```

I understood the basic logic, but have no idea what does `List * list` means. Shouldn't it be `List *list` to specify it as a `List` struct? Why it has to be `List * list`?

Comment: It doesn't matter: `List* list` or `List * list` or `List *list` but IMO prefer the last.

Comment: Whitespace is only mandatory if its missing will lead to other language tokens, like concatenated symbols, or in expressions like `v = 3 + +i;`. Else it is optional, use it as you see fit or the project's coding guide requests.

Comment: I prefer the first because it makes it clearer to me that `list` is a `List*` , i.e. a "Pointer to a `List`", but opinions differ here, as you see :)

Comment: I prefer the last because it makes it clearer to me that `List* a, b, c;` only defines *one* pointer variable. This is clearer with `List *a, b, c;` and I stick to the same convention in other circumstances.